# What is the difference between viewing aws custom metrics on aws console vs configuring it on grafana?

Tags: metrics, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

What are the advantages we get when custom metrics view on grafana instead of aws cloudwatch console itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main advantage is if you are already using Grafana for other monitoring then you can have your Cloudwatch metrics together with your other metrics.

If you don't use Grafana then it would be overkill to install it just for Cloudwatch in my opinion.

Other advantages:

- templating (dropdown lists). See this dashboard for an [example](https://grafana.com/dashboards/590).
- Can put them on a TV in your office. We have stats for S3 downloads on our TV (together with other stats for our website):
  [image]
- And soon, there will be support for alerting in Grafana for Cloudwatch.